# How can do when the user reject permissions in the app?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-maps

I am developing an app which the main function is a see data on a map.

For this, I need to get the current position, and for this, I request to user.

But if the user rejects the permissions, what is the best way to ask again for it?

I try asking again in `onRequestPermissionsResult` but the app crash.

Any idea?

**Code:**

```
private void enableMyLocationIfPermitted() {    
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (mapViewModel.getGoogleMap() != null) {
            mapViewModel.getGoogleMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "No Google Map available in view model");
        }
     } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
     }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Map is ready");
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mapViewModel.setGoogleMap(googleMap);
    enableMyLocationIfPermitted();
    getLastLocationIfPermitted();
    mapViewModel.loadData();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    enableMyLocationIfPermitted();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getText(R.string.you_need_permissions), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
         }

     }
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Thanks

Comment: Share your code and stack trace (from crash)

Comment: Share your crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user denied permission with "Never ask again" option, your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method would call itself forever until it throws `StackOverFlowError`.

The best thing to do here is to not ask permission again in the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method once user denies it. Rather you can disable the feature or you can open the permission settings of your app and have them manually change the permission settings using below code.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                enableMyLocationIfPermitted();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getText(R.string.you_need_permissions), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to read more on the permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting this is a good guide.

Comment: ok anyway, the crash happen in onLoad, and before of I can response

Comment: Just remove `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);` from onRequestPermissionsResult method

Comment: yes but if I remove that and the user reject the permission, what is the best way of request it again?

Comment: If your app can't function without the permission then you must close the app by 'finish();` then when the user opens it back again the app will be asked for the permission if  "Never ask again" not chosen.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES I've edited my code with a better suggestion

Comment: Maybe another option can be launch again the activity?, thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

**StackOverflow** -> This usually means that you have a recursive call in your code. Recursion is simply a method that calls itself, causing the stack to overflow and throw the StackOverflow exception.

Probably application doesn't ask again to the user if user rejects the permission. Then this flow behaves like an infinity loop. And you are getting crash when you pass over stack size

Answer (score 1):

If user reject permission means the user did not want to share his/her data with your app, then why you want to ask it repeatedly, it's annoying to the user, You simply put a message to let user know why you are asking permission and in case of denying user are not able to use specific feature of the app, Still you want to ask for permission repeatedly you just need to show dialog when user deny with prompt "PLease allow this permission for further app use"
and when user press ok show permission dialog again.

Comment: Because is a required feature, I think the same put in settings an option, and maybe the user reject by error. because the only functionality of the app is to look a map with data that use your location.